# When I click a button it should display the html page in angularjs(single page application)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am going to design a website That should display the content of html  when I click a button.

HTML

```
 <a ui-sref="about">about</a>
    <a href="" ng-click="home()" >home</a><div ng-include="templateURL"></div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
```

JS:

```
 app.controller("home", hom); function hom($scope) {
  $scope.home = function(){
   $scope.templateURL = 'templates/hello.html';  }}
```

Comment: If you are trying to show pages when hyperlinks are clicked, then use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). This might take some time to learn but it is recommended and useful.

Comment: ok...but how to implement controller for ui-router...could you please help me...its really urjent..and Thanks

Comment: You can follow [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router).

Comment: is this correct implementation of controller to return a html page()..                                                                                          function Fun3controller($scope, $uibModal) {  
  var modalInstance;
    $scope.open= function () {
        modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'templates/Fun3.html',
            controller: 'Fun3controller'
        })
        .result.then(
            function () {
                //alert("OK");
            }, 
            function () {
                //alert("Cancel");
            }
        );

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your problem is **ngRoute / ui-route**.
You can one of the above-mentioned solutions.

check demo here:
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: is this correct implementation of controller to return a html page().. function Fun3controller($scope, $uibModal)   {                                               var modalInstance; $scope.open= function () {                     modalInstance = $uibModal.open({                                          
  templateUrl: 'templates/Fun3.html',                                                   controller: 'Fun3controller' }) .result.then( function () { //alert("OK"); }, function () { //alert("Cancel"); } )

Comment: check out this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jnrl5aT3A8&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWKHkcL7RJmmXyxkuFB3KSl&index=42